# Tagging values in HTML document for automated extraction

Tags: xml, html

We have a series of documents that are being converted to HTML for web access. The documents are operating instructions that list actions people have to do as well as distinct requirements. We wanted to put a tag around each requirement so it can be automatically extracted using some code. The approach I took was to enclose each requirement with a comment: `<!-- Requirement Start --> THE REQUIREMENT HERE <!-- Requirement End -->`

I created a routine that parses the document and gets all of the requirements from the documents. One of my users says I should use XML markup and create the markup like `<requirement> THE REQUIREMENT HERE </requirement>`.

I'm not sure what is the correct approach. The driving factor for me is that the actual tag (not the content between the opening/closing tags) be hidden when looking at the screen in the browser window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using them as meta-documents and they are sent to the parser, then converted as HTML and as long as the converted HTMLs do not have any irrelevant tags, it is fine! So, if the following code:

```
<requirement> THE REQUIREMENT HERE </requirement>
```

Gets converted into something like:

```
<!-- Requirement Start -->
  HTML OF THE REQUIREMENT HERE
<!-- Requirement End -->
```

It would be safe to use custom tags as they are always valid in XML.

Comment: I gather you're saying either is ok, but are you giving preference to either one?

Comment: I will go for the `requirement` tag! If there's a preprocessor before HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine, but I'd recommend doing something different with your comment tags.  Think about how your parser will know whether this comment tag is actually a comment or a markup directive.  You may want to come up with a short sequence of characters that's unlikely to occur in an actual comment, for example:

```
<!-- $!requirement$! -->
```

This way, you can just parse the first couple characters.  If they're not `$!`, then you know this is just an ordinary comment that was left in the file, and you should ignore it; if they are `$!`, then you need to convert them to a tag.

Comment: I'm using regular expressions in my parser, but I think you make a good point.